# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL in M 2.2.*

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v2

I am facing following issue at my local environment I tried every solution available on internet but unable to fix this issue.
[image]
 I am using LAMP PHP 7.1.28-1+ubuntu18.04, Apache/2.4.39

I had created virtual host for: www.fytm.com
This issue is only at my local url if I change it to any live server url it works.

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.fytm.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=storeStoreRepositoryV1,catalogAttributeSetRepositoryV1,catalogProductAttributeRepositoryV1,catalogProductRepositoryV1,catalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1,catalogProductCustomOptionRepositoryV1,salesOrderItemRepositoryV1,salesOrderRepositoryV1' : Couldn't find end of Start Tag appinfo line 2
```